# etymology of phosphatidates and phosphatidic acid

Tags: nomenclature

A phosphatidic acid is an ester of a glycerol, two fatty acids and a phosphoric acid.
Who coined this term, and is the word's "phat" part related to english "fat"?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, "phosphatidate" is from "phosphate" + "-ide" + "-ate".

The word "phosphatidic acid" is from "phosphate" + "-ide" + "-ic acid".

Phosphate ($\ce{PO4^3-}$) is the anion of phosphoric acid ($\ce{H3PO4}$).

The suffix "-ide" is used in biochemistry to just about anything. It just denotes an element of a group of related compounds.

Now, "-ate" and "-ic acid" denotes the acidic nature of the compounds.

---

And no, it is not related to the English word "fat".

Answer (score 6):

Phosphatidate can be broken down to "Phosph(orous) + at(e) + id(e) + ate"

-ate means either "having" or "characterised by" and is used in chemistry to denote esp. a salt or ester of an acid.

-ide is a suffix meaning "a compound of " or to denote a group of relate do compounds as in monosacchar**ide** or to indicate that is a binary compound as in Sodium chloride.

-ic also means relating to or characterised by.

Therefore phosphatidate literally means it's a compound containing a moiety characterised by having an ester of phosphorus.

> Who coined this term?

According to [this site](http://www.memidex.com/phosphatide#etymology) it was 1st used in 1884 by International scientific vocabulary.

Comment: Can it be one of "ate" was for phosphoric acid, and other for fatty acid. and ide for glycerol ( like a monosaccharide)?

Comment: Yes it could be.